# Rails 4 - Invalid route name, already in use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a problem with routing in Rails 4 on production.

My config/route.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}", status: 302), as: :redirected_root
  post '/rate' => 'rater#create', :as => 'rate'

  scope ':locale', defaults: {locale: I18n.locale} do
    ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  end

  scope ':locale', locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/  do

    devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
    devise_for :users

    # post '/rate' => 'rater#create', :as => 'rate'


    root :controller => 'static', :action => 'index'

    resources :categories

    resources :authors

    resources :messages

    resources :books

    resources :tags

    resource :static

    resource :users

  end
  # match '/:locale' => 'static#index'
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Each route return error: Invalid route name, already in use...

Maybe you know why this is happening? 
I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: You have declare two scope ':locale' in you routes this could be the problem.

Comment: unfortunately It's not the problem, I had check it and nothing changed. Routes which are not in the 'local' declarations also return s the problem. It looks like the file is duplicate but I also check it and I didn't find.